# How to ignore Symbols in string comparison and dictionary lookup

Tags: c#, symbols

It looks like I have a problem with the symbols encodings between string built by my program and string retrieved from another datasource.

Here is a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vfA8Aw) and here is the explanation:

```
var context = new List<Foo>
{
    new Foo { Name = "SoW.Probing.4GEPCCore.CaptSite[1].S1U" },
    new Foo { Name = "SoW.Probing.4GEPCCore.CaptSite[2].S1U" },
    new Foo { Name = "SoW.Probing.2G3GPSCore.CaptSite[1].GnGpU" },
    new Foo { Name = "SoW.Probing.2G3GPSCore.CaptSite[2].GnGpU" }
};

var nameToCheckPresence = GetStringFromAnotherDataSource(); // the value of the string is for example: "SoW.Probing.4GEPCCore.CaptSite.S1U"

nameToCheckPresence = nameToCheckPresence.Replace("CaptSite", "CaptSite[1]");

var foo = context.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == nameToCheckPresence); // Should return an object since one object does have that name
```

My problem is that `foo` is null. It works if I use this code line:

```
var foo = context .FirstOrDefault(f => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(f.Name, nameToCheckPresence , CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols) == 0);
```

So clearly, I have a problem with symbols encoding (the `.`? the `[` `]`?). My true problem is that later, I am doing the same thing with a dictionary. The hashcode of the strings are different and the dictionary lookup also failed:

```
var dictionary = context.ToDictionary(f => f.Name);

var foo = dictionary[nameToCheckPresence]; // Should return the object but failed and throw a KeyNotFoundException
```

Is there a way to change the string symbols encoding in a global manner in the application? (WPF application in my case)

As the `context` can be very large, it is planed to use a Dictionary also in the first place. So if you provide me a solution that only works with Dictionary, it is not a problem.

Just for the record, the datasource is a SQLite database in which is a copy of the data of a MySQL database filled by another WPF application (running on the same computer, no specific culture setup). Finally, the `nameToCheckPresence` is extracted from a larger string by [`ANTLR4CS`](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs).

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you'd provide a [mcve] and focus on *one* question in your post, rather than just *describing* a lot of code, then asking multiple questions. (It's not clear that this has *anything to do with WPF, either.)

Comment: I would like to provide such an example but it is very difficult because the code is splited into a lot of classes and resources files (I cannot provide you my whole ANTLR grammar, parser, visitor, etc). You are right, WPF is a wrong key word, I removed it!

Comment: You don't need to provide all the ANTLR parts etc. Just a complete example of the part that's causing the problem. It's absolutely fine for that to have hard-coded input. You should make it as small as you can - if the ANTLR part is irrelevant, don't include it. If MySQL is irrelevant, don't include that. It sounds like you're only interested in a dictionary lookup, which really doesn't depend on either of those things.

Comment: I hope it is better now!

Comment: Not really. Try to create an [mvce] using the actual values of the strings that cause the problem. You can also try to use [dot fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) to create a self contained working example. If you can't get the actual values to copy correctly see if you can convert the string to a byte representation and copy the byte array to the sample code and then reverse that back to a string in the running code.

Comment: Just added a fiddle.

Comment: In your fiddle example, referentiel has a trailing space, so one approach might be to `Trim` whitespace from this string before adding to the dictionary.  Alternatively, you can specify a custom `IEqualityComparer<string>` as an argument to `ToDictionary`.  The custom comparer can be implemented to ignore symbols.

Comment: Oh ... I am feeling so bad for missing that ... You can write write it as answer if you want to. It perfectly answers my issues !

Answer (score 0):

This is not a satisfactory answer, but that's all I find to solve the problem. Instead of looking into the dictionary through the indexor, I am doing a linq query:

```
dictionary.FirstOrDefault(pair => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(pair.Key, localFactName, CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols) == 0).Value;
```

But doing this, I lost all the benefit of the dictionary access complexity. If anyone has a better solution, I will take it!